# Making Iterative Dates in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, data-science

I have a problem statement as follows:

In each examination centre, exam is to be organised in two shifts batch I & batch II(reporting time 9:00 AM & 2 PM). Exam can be conducted at any day in a district during December 1-30, 2020 depending upon the number of candidates in a district. Note in each district only one examination centre is possible and in one shift maximum 20 students can appear. Based on the information mentioned above complete the examination database by allocating:

- **Rollno**: Roll number of the candidate will start from NL2000001 onwards(eg: NL2000001, NL2000002, NL2000003……)
- **cent_allot**: allocate centre by putting examination city code
- **cent_add**: put NL "District Name" as center address in each location (for eg if district name is ADI then centre add is NL ADI)
- **examDate**: Allocate any exam date between December 1,2020 to December 30, 2020 keeping minimum no of examination days and not violating any conditions mentioned above
- **batch**: allocate batch I or II ensuring all the conditions mentioned above
- **rep_time**: for batch I reporting time is 9 AM and for batch II reporting time is 2 PM.

As per the above description, I need to make a table which satisfies the above conditions. I have already made the **Rollno**, **cent_allot** and **cent_add** columns, but I am struggling in making the **examDate** column, since it should have same date for every 40 values of district.

Here is the list of the districts and their frequency of occurrences:

```
Dist    Count
WGL     299
MAHB    289
KUN     249
GUN     198
KARN    196
KRS     171
CTT     169
VIZ     150
PRA     145
NALG    130
MED     128
ADI     123
KPM     119
TRI     107
ANA     107
KHAM    85
NEL     85
VIZI    84
EGOD    84
SOA     84
SIR     80
NIZA    73
PUD     70
KRK     69
WGOD    56
```

Here is the first 25 rows of the dataframe:

```
Rollno     cent_allot   cent_add    examDate    batch   rep_time
NL2000001   WGL          NL WGL       NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000002   WGL          NL WGL       NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000003   WGL          NL WGL       NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000004   KUN          NL KUN       NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000005   KUN          NL KUN       NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000006   KUN          NL KUN       NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000007   GUN          NL GUN       NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000008   GUN          NL GUN       NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000009   GUN          NL GUN       NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000010   GUN          NL GUN       NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000011   VIZ          NL VIZ       NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000012   VIZ          NL VIZ       NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000013   VIZ          NL VIZ       NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000014   VIZ          NL VIZ       NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000015   MAHB         NL MAHB      NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000016   MAHB         NL MAHB      NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000017   MAHB         NL MAHB      NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000018   WGOD         NL WGOD      NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000019   WGOD         NL WGOD      NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000020   WGOD         NL WGOD      NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000021   WGOD         NL WGOD      NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000022   EGOD         NL EGOD      NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000023   EGOD         NL EGOD      NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000024   EGOD         NL EGOD      NaN        NaN    NaN
NL2000025   EGOD         NL EGOD      NaN        NaN    NaN
```

The last 3 columns are all **NaN**s as these three columns are yet to be made.

Let's take `WGL` for example. As per the above description, maximum 20 candidates can be allowed per shift per district, which implies that the same date is to be allotted 40 times to each district, and the same batch and the same reporting time needs to be allotted 20 times to each districs.

Does anyone have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had struggled a lot for getting the solution, but finally at the end of that day when I asked the question I found a solution:

```
# examDate column

n_stud = 20   # mention the number of students per batch here
n_batch = 2   # mention the number of batches per day here

temp = data['TH_CENT_CH'].value_counts().sort_index().reset_index()  # storing centers and their counts in a temp variable
cent = temp['index'].to_list()      # storing centers in a list
cnt = temp['TH_CENT_CH'].to_list()  # storing counts in a list
cent1 = []
cnt1 = []
j = 0

# for loops to repeat each center by count times
for c in cent:
    for i in range(1, cnt[j] + 1):
        cent1.append(c)
        cnt1.append(i)
    j += 1

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(cent1, cnt1)), columns = ['cent','cnt'])  # dataframe to store the centers and new count list

counts = df1['cnt'].to_list() # storing the new counts in a list
helper = {}  # helper dictionary
max_no = max(cnt)

# for-while loops to map helper number to each counts number
for i in counts:
    j = 0
    while(j < (round(max_no / (n_stud * n_batch)) + 1)):
        if((i > (n_stud * n_batch * j)) & (i < (n_stud * n_batch * (i + 1)))):
            helper[i] = j
        j += 1

# mapping the helper with counts
counts = pd.Series(counts)
helper = pd.Series(helper)
hel = counts.map(helper).to_list()
df1['helper'] = hel

examDate = {}  # dictionary to store exam dates

# for loop to map dates to each helper number
for i in hel:
    examDate[i] = pd.to_datetime(date(2020, 12, 1) + timedelta(days = (2 * i)))

# mapping the dates with helpers
hel = pd.Series(hel)
examDate = pd.Series(examDate)
exam = hel.map(examDate).to_list()
df1['examDate'] = exam
        
# adding the dates to the original dataframe
examDate = df1['examDate'].to_list()
data['examDate'] = examDate
data['examDate']
```

Here `TH_CENT_CH` refers to the district column in the original dataframe. When I ran `data.head()`, then I get the output that I needed, i.e. one date for 40 students. I did similar thing for the remaining two columns, where I needed to have same batch for 20 students. And so I got output as:

```
        Rollno  cent_allot  cent_add  examDate   batch  rep_time
0     NL2000001        ADI   NL ADI  2020-12-01      1  09:00:00
1     NL2000002        ADI   NL ADI  2020-12-01      1  09:00:00
2     NL2000003        ADI   NL ADI  2020-12-01      1  09:00:00
3     NL2000004        ADI   NL ADI  2020-12-01      1  09:00:00
4     NL2000005        ADI   NL ADI  2020-12-01      1  09:00:00
         ...        ...      ...         ...    ...       ...
3345  NL2003346        WGOD  NL WGOD 2020-12-03      1  09:00:00
3346  NL2003347        WGOD  NL WGOD 2020-12-04      1  09:00:00
3347  NL2003348         KRS  NL KRS  2020-12-05      1  09:00:00
3348  NL2003349        WGOD  NL WGOD 2020-12-02      1  09:00:00
3349  NL2003350        WGOD  NL WGOD 2020-12-04      1  09:00:00
```

Please find the code for the remaining two columns:

```
# batch column

counts = df1['cnt'].to_list()  # storing the new counts in a list
helper2 = {}  # helper dictionary

# for-while loops to map helper number to each counts number
for i in counts:
    j = 0
    while(j < (round(max_no / (n_stud)) + 1)):
        if((i > (n_stud * j)) & (i < (n_stud * (i + 1)))):
            helper2[i] = j
        j += 1

# mapping the helper with counts
counts = pd.Series(counts)
helper2 = pd.Series(helper2)
hel2 = counts.map(helper2).to_list()
df1['helper2'] = hel2

batch = {}   # dictionary to store batch numbers

# for loop to map batch numbers to each helper number
for i in hel2:
    if(i % 2 == 0):
        batch[i] = 1
    else:
        batch[i] = 2
        
# mapping the batches with helpers
hel2 = pd.Series(hel2)
batch = pd.Series(batch)
bat = hel2.map(batch).to_list()
df1['batch'] = bat

# adding the batches to the original dataframe
batch = df1['batch'].to_list()
data['batch'] = batch
data['batch'].unique()

# rep_time column
data.loc[data['batch'] == 1, 'rep_time'] = '9:00 AM'
data.loc[data['batch'] == 2, 'rep_time'] = '2:00 PM'
data['rep_time'].unique()
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use `.groupby().cumcount()` to get the running number first. The `examDate` and `batch` can be subsequently determined respectively by the modulus of the running number against 40 and 20.

## Data

Random rows are generated using the given total count for each `Dist`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import io
import datetime

df_count = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
Dist    Count
WGL     299
MAHB    289
KUN     249
GUN     198
KARN    196
KRS     171
CTT     169
VIZ     150
PRA     145
NALG    130
MED     128
ADI     123
KPM     119
TRI     107
ANA     107
KHAM    85
NEL     85
VIZI    84
EGOD    84
SOA     84
SIR     80
NIZA    73
PUD     70
KRK     69
WGOD    56
"""), sep=r"\s{2,}", engine="python")

# generate random cent_allot
df = df_count.loc[np.repeat(df_count.index.values, df_count["Count"]), "Dist"]\
    .sample(frac=1)\
    .reset_index(drop=True)\
    .to_frame()\
    .rename(columns={"Dist": "cent_allot"})

df["Rollno"] = df.index.map(lambda s: f"NL2{s+1:06}")
df["cent_add"] = df["cent_allot"].map(lambda s: f"NL {s}")
```

`df` up to here should resemble what you've had.

## Code

```
# Assign the first examDate
first_day = datetime.date(2020, 12, 1)

# running no. grouped by "cent_allot" (i.e. "Dist")
df["gp_no"] = df.groupby("cent_allot").cumcount()

# increase one day for every 40 records
df["examDate"] = df["gp_no"].apply(lambda x: first_day + datetime.timedelta(days=int(x / 40)))

# batch - can be determined by the even-ness of int(no. / 20)
df["batch"] = df["gp_no"].apply(lambda x: 1 + int(x / 20) % 2)

# map batch to time (or "9 AM" / "2 PM" as you'd like)
df["rep_time"] = df["batch"].apply(lambda x: datetime.time(9, 0) if x == 1 else datetime.time(14, 0))
```

## Output

```
print(df[["Rollno", "cent_allot", "cent_add", "examDate", "batch", "rep_time"]])

         Rollno cent_allot cent_add    examDate  batch  rep_time
0     NL2000001        CTT   NL CTT  2020-12-01      1  09:00:00
1     NL2000002       MAHB  NL MAHB  2020-12-01      1  09:00:00
2     NL2000003        CTT   NL CTT  2020-12-01      1  09:00:00
3     NL2000004        SOA   NL SOA  2020-12-01      1  09:00:00
4     NL2000005        PUD   NL PUD  2020-12-01      1  09:00:00
         ...        ...      ...         ...    ...       ...
3345  NL2003346       KHAM  NL KHAM  2020-12-03      1  09:00:00
3346  NL2003347        ADI   NL ADI  2020-12-04      1  09:00:00
3347  NL2003348       KARN  NL KARN  2020-12-05      2  14:00:00
3348  NL2003349        SIR   NL SIR  2020-12-02      2  14:00:00
3349  NL2003350        ADI   NL ADI  2020-12-04      1  09:00:00

[3350 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: thanks for your code. Your code looks concise and appropriate. I didn't run your code as I figured a tedious solution for it myself, but still I really appreciate tour help. Thanks for your help...